# read parameter value in dataservice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have controller

```
homemodule.controller("productController", function ($scope, $http, $resource, dataServiceSingleProduct, $routeParams) {
    $scope.data = dataServiceSingleProduct;

    dataServiceSingleProduct.getProduct()
    .then(function () {
        //success

    },
    function () {
        // error
        alert("could not load product");
    });
});
```

and data service

```
homemodule.factory("dataServiceSingleProduct", function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        product: _product,
        getProduct: _getProduct
    };

    // implementation    
    var _product = [];
    var _getProduct = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get("/Data/GetProduct", { params: { "id": 2 } })
        .then(function (result) {
            // success
            angular.copy(result.data, _product);
            deferred.resolve();
        },
        function () {
            // error
            deferred.reject();
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});
```

This works with this hardcoded parameter id  (`params: { "id": 2 }`)

My question is:

How can I send read id parameter in dataServiceSingleProduct service.

*It's available on controller using $routeParams.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In controller:

```
var id = $routeParams.id;
dataServiceSingleProduct.getProduct(id).then(function(data) {
    // ...
});
```

In service:

```
var _getProduct = function(id) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get("/Data/GetProduct", { params: {id: id} }).then(function(result) {
        angular.copy(result.data, _product);
        deferred.resolve();
    }, function () {
        // error
        deferred.reject();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

or even better providing that `$http.get` already returns a promise, so no need to create another one:

```
var _getProduct = function(id) {
    return $http.get("/Data/GetProduct", { params: {id: id} }).then(function(result) {
        return angular.copy(result.data, _product);
    }, function() {
        $q.reject();
    });
};
```

Note how you return modified promise from `then` success function. Also in order to reject a promise you simply use `$q.reject` to reject current one.